# How to escape @ character in proxy password string when making http request in Python

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests, basic-authentication, http-proxy

How to escape `@` character in the password of proxy. Below is how my proxy string looks like, I am using python requests module for making the http request.

```
import requests

# Reading from environment though
PROXY_STRING = "http://UserName:Pass@Word@X.X.X.X:Port_No"

PROXY = {
    'https': PROXY_STRING,
    'http': PROXY_STRING
}

resp = requests.get(some_url, proxies=PROXY)
```

When I ran the above code, it is returning the below message:
 `Please check proxy URL. It is malformed and could be missing the host.`

I also tried using the URL encoded value of the `@` symbol which is `%40` as shown here.
`PROXY_STRING = "http://UserName:Pass%40Word@X.X.X.X:Port_No"`

But it is returning the below message
`Failed to parse: http://UserName:Pass%40Word@X.X.X.X:Port_No`

So, how to escape `@` in proxy connection string (in my case, it is in the password). I cannot have an option to change the password.

**My Environment:** OS - Windows 8.1 Enterprise, requests 2.22.0, Python 3.6.2

**Note:** I tried by updating my environment to `Python 3.8` and `requests 0.23.0`, still it is throwing the same exception - `requests.exceptions.InvalidProxyURL: Please check proxy URL. It is malformed and could be missing the host.`

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: requests is using `urlparse`  from `urllib.parse`. It should parse that username and password even with the `@` are you sure that is the issue with it?

Comment: Yes @Dror Av. It is throwing the following exception: `requests.exceptions.InvalidProxyURL: Please check proxy URL. It is malformed and could be missing the host.`

Comment: I tested it on my machine and it seemed to work fine, `Python3.8`, `requests 2.23.0`. Maybe update requests and Python if it is possible and try again though I don't think urlparse was changed significally from 3.6

Comment: Not sure how it worked on your machine. I just updated to `Python 3.8` and `requests 2.23.0`, still it is throwing the same exception as before.